# Converting list of lists of differing lenghts within dataframe into long format dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm seeking a dplyr-ish solution to the following task. I have a data frame that contains a variable that is a list of lists which has an attribute dimnames. The lists are of different lengths. Here's the output to `str(df)`:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Step : int  1 2 3
 $ Value:List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 0.232 0.261 0.932 0.875
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "4" "5"
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "0.2" "0.094"
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:5] 0.197 0.197 0.64 0.643 0.958 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "4" "5"
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "0.2" "0.094" "0.044" "0.021" ...
  ..$ : num [1:2, 1] 0.268 0.262
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "4" "5"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "0.2"
```

I've included dput code below to recreate this dataframe.

I want a dataframe in the following format:

```
Step    Value   a     b
 1      0.232   4   0.200
 1      0.261   5   0.200
 1      0.932   4   0.094
 1      0.875   5   0.094
 1       NA     4   0.044
 1       NA     5   0.044
 1       NA     4   0.021
 1       NA     5   0.021
 1       NA     4   0.010
 1       NA     5   0.010
 2      0.197   4   0.200
 2      0.197   5   0.200
 2      0.640   4   0.094
 2      0.643   5   0.094
 2      0.958   4   0.044
 2      1.032   5   0.044
 2      0.943   4   0.021
 2      1.119   5   0.021
 2      0.943   4   0.010
 2      1.119   5   0.010
 3      0.268   4   0.200
 3      0.262   5   0.200
 3       NA     4   0.094
 3       NA     5   0.094
 3       NA     4   0.044
 3       NA     5   0.044
 3       NA     4   0.021
 3       NA     5   0.021
 3       NA     4   0.010
 3       NA     5   0.010
```

where the variable `a` are the row names of the list of lists dimnames and `b` are the column names.

I've tried a `for` loop to separate out each list by step, but

1. I've not been successful in padding out the list with `NA`s (`length(x) <- y` doesn't work).
2. I've reviewed [advanced R data types](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) but haven't been successful in extracting the dimnames into vectors to use as dataframe columns (`attr(df$Value, "dimnames")` yields `NULL`.)

Once I have lists of the same length I can construct the new dataframe vectors step by step in the `for` loop and then rbind. Or is there a way to use the dimname attribute to directly construct a wide dataframe using both row and column dimnames as dataframe column names? I can then `gather` to make a long dataframe.

There's several subquestions here, and I'm sure there's a more elegant solution than the one I've mapped out. Thanks for looking.

Here's the dput code to create the dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Step = c(1L, 2L, 3L), Value = list(structure(c(0.232, 
0.261, 0.932, 0.875), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("4", "5"), c("0.2", "0.094"
))), structure(c(0.197, 0.197, 0.640, 
0.643, 0.958, 1.032, 0.943, 
1.119, 0.943, 1.119), .Dim = c(2L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("4", "5"), c("0.2", "0.094", 
"0.044", "0.021", "0.01"))), structure(c(0.268, 
0.262), .Dim = c(2L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("4", 
"5"), "0.2")))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .Names = c("Step", "Value"))
```

Comment: Looks like that variable is list of matrices, not a lists of lists?

Comment: Could be, `str(df$Value[[1]])` yields `num [1:2, 1:2] 0.232 0.261 0.932 0.875
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "4" "5"
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "0.2" "0.094"`, but then isn't a matrix a list with dimensional attributes, and I still need to convert to a long dataframe using the dimnames as variables. I can't figure a way to untangle this object.

Comment: Yeah ok, `num [1:2, 1:2]` means numerical array with two dimension, i.e. a matrix. It's only the dimnames that are a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach one:

First, we get the matrices to data.frames, then we add the rownames as a separate column called `a`, and gather them all. By unnesting we get one big data.frame. Adding in the `NA` values is easy with `complete`

```
library(tidyverse) # using dplyr, tidyr and purrr

df %>% 
  mutate(Value = map(Value, as.data.frame),
         Value = map(Value, rownames_to_column, 'a'),
         Value = map(Value, ~gather(., b, value, -a))) %>% 
  unnest(Value) %>% 
  complete(Step, a, b)
```

#### Approach two:

Manually define the data.frame, then do the same:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Value = map(Value, 
                     ~data_frame(val = c(.), 
                                 a = rep(rownames(.), each = ncol(.)),
                                 b = rep(colnames(.), nrow(.))))) %>% 
  unnest(Value) %>% 
  complete(Step, a, b))
```

#### Result:

Both give:

> ```
> # A tibble: 30 × 4
>     Step     a     b value
>    <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
> 1      1     4  0.01    NA
> 2      1     4 0.021    NA
> 3      1     4 0.044    NA
> 4      1     4 0.094 0.932
> 5      1     4   0.2 0.232
> 6      1     5  0.01    NA
> 7      1     5 0.021    NA
> 8      1     5 0.044    NA
> 9      1     5 0.094 0.875
> 10     1     5   0.2 0.261
> # ... with 20 more rows
> ```

Comment: I'm speechless, so quickly and not one but two options. Let me play with these and I'll get back to you. I'm sure I'll have questions.

Comment: That does it, and fast with my real dataframe. I had no idea it would be THIS easy and I've picked up several nifty tricks.  I've used map with functions, but not with value setting before, and I'd not seen complete.   What does the ~ do?

Comment: It's one of the ways to define an anonymous function in `purrr`. See the `.f` argument of `?map`.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a `dplyr` solution, but you could do:

```
## Get the maximum length in l$Value and the index where it is observed
m = max(lengths(l$Value))
[1] 10
j = which.max(lengths(l$Value))
[1] 2
```

Then construct a dataframe for each element of `l$Value`, `rbind` them together and add the `Step` column:

```
l2 = lapply(l$Value,function(x) data.frame(a=rep(row.names(x),length.out=m),
Value=x[1:m],b=rep(colnames(l$Value[[j]]),length.out=m)))
df = do.call(rbind,l2)
df$Step = rep(l$Step,each=m)
```

This returns:

```
   a Value     b Step
1  4 0.232   0.2    1
2  5 0.261 0.094    1
3  4 0.932 0.044    1
4  5 0.875 0.021    1
5  4    NA  0.01    1
6  5    NA   0.2    1
7  4    NA 0.094    1
8  5    NA 0.044    1
9  4    NA 0.021    1
10 5    NA  0.01    1
11 4 0.197   0.2    2
12 5 0.197 0.094    2
13 4 0.640 0.044    2
14 5 0.643 0.021    2
15 4 0.958  0.01    2
16 5 1.032   0.2    2
17 4 0.943 0.094    2
18 5 1.119 0.044    2
19 4 0.943 0.021    2
20 5 1.119  0.01    2
21 4 0.268   0.2    3
22 5 0.262 0.094    3
23 4    NA 0.044    3
24 5    NA 0.021    3
25 4    NA  0.01    3
26 5    NA   0.2    3
27 4    NA 0.094    3
28 5    NA 0.044    3
29 4    NA 0.021    3
30 5    NA  0.01    3
```